# Data table/frame: Assign numbers to a column based on the order of values in another column

Tags: r

I am trying to create a new column (*expected_result* in the table below) which is assigned numbers based on 'how many different stimulus between the two same stimuli' (1 if the last row is the same stimulus, 2 if the last last row is the same stimulus, etc.). Also, the first time the stimulus appear is 1 but not 0.

In my example below,

1. the first element for column *stimulus* is *'CS'*, so the expected result is *'1'*.
2. the second and the third element for column *stimulus* are still *'CS'*, for both of them, the last row is the same element as itself, so the expected result is still *'1'*.
3. For the next *'CS'* after the third row (which is row 6), there are 3 rows before the last *'CS'*, so the expected result is *3*.

I want to apply this rule to every element in column stimulus

[image]

**Example data**

```
example <- structure(list(stimulus = c("CS", "CS", "CS", "S2", "S2", "CS", 
"S3", "S2", "S3"), expected_result = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 
2)), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
))
```

Comment: I don't understand your question - could you be clearer?

Comment: @DanielV, sorry, I added some explanations in the question, hope it is more clear now. The rule is 'to assign number dependent on how many rows to the last same element in the column, and assign 1 rather than 0 when there is 0 row to the last same element (first time appear)'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a `data.table` approach.
Calculated results are in the `result`-column.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(example)
example[, id := .I]
example[, result := id - shift(id, type = "lag", fill = (id[1] - 1)), by = .(stimulus)][]
#    stimulus expected_result id result
# 1:       CS               1  1      1
# 2:       CS               1  2      1
# 3:       CS               1  3      1
# 4:       S2               1  4      1
# 5:       S2               1  5      1
# 6:       CS               3  6      3
# 7:       S3               1  7      1
# 8:       S2               3  8      3
# 9:       S3               2  9      2
```